# How can I run JavaScript for Automation script from Python?

Tags: macos, applescript, python, javascript-automation

With the [py-applescript](https://github.com/rdhyee/py-applescript) package for Python, it is straightforward to run an AppleScript from Python without having to run a separate `osascript` subprocess:

```py
import applescript
applescript.AppleScript('say "Hello AppleScript"').run()
```

Is there a similar way to run [JavaScript for Automation](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook) scripts from Python (i.e., without invoking `osascript` as a subprocess)?

**Further elaboration**: I'm asking how to run JavaScript (specifically [JXA](https://github.com/JXA-Cookbook/JXA-Cookbook/wiki)), not AppleScript, in a manner analogous to how you can interact with AppleScript via [py-applescript](https://github.com/rdhyee/py-applescript) or [more directly using AppleScriptObjC](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) . You can't hand JavaScript syntax to a call to the `AppleScript` function from the [py-applescript](https://github.com/rdhyee/py-applescript) package, but perhaps there is a different package, one that offers a Python-JXA interface, that I haven't found.  Is there one?

Comment: What script do you have and what happens when you call it the exact same as above?

Comment: @bmike Errm, I'm asking how to run JavaScript, not AppleScript :-). You can't hand JavaScript syntax to a call to the `AppleScript` function from the py-applescript package. Any simple example will demonstrate it fails. E.g., `applescript.AppleScript('Application("iTunes").currentTrack.name()')`. Perhaps the point of your question is to make me add more information? If so, I will.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of using python to write the file to a temporary location and the execute it - but that might not be the answer you seek... basically avoiding you needing a bridge or bindings to a specific JS engine and use a << HERE idiom from bash...

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Yeah, running an external process is what I'm trying to avoid. Maybe this is a quixotic quest, but I'm trying to see if there's a way to do it more directly. The situation is, I write stuff in Python and want to interact with Mac applications. I'm trying to see if there's a way to use JavaScript syntax instead of AppleScript syntax.

Comment: I love it - won’t have an answer till I can experiment. Clean scripts are the best for readability and support. +1